# Libreoffice API (UNO) : text and data from xTextField

Tags: c++, libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-writer

How can I get xTextFields from .odt document properly?

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work (Any returns a nullptr address):

```
Reference <XTextFieldsSupplier> xTextFieldsSupplier (xTextDoc, UNO_QUERY);
if (!xTextFieldsSupplier.is())
    return { };

Reference<XNameAccess> xTextFieldsInfo = xTextFieldsSupplier->getTextFieldMasters();
if (!xTextFieldsInfo.is())
    return { };

Sequence<OUString> xTextFieldsNames = xTextFieldsInfo->getElementNames();

Any any;
for (::rtl::OUString* field = xTextFieldsNames.begin();
        field != xTextFieldsNames.end();
        field++) {
    std::stringstream field_string;
    field_string << *field;
    QString fieldName = QString::fromStdString(field_string.str());
    any = xTextFieldsInfo->getByName(*field);

    Reference< XTextField > xField(any, UNO_QUERY);

    // other code to work with xField
}
```

**UPD**:

I got a solution that helped me here:
[Libreoffice API (UNO): need to change user's xTextField text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769483/libreoffice-api-uno-need-to-change-users-xtextfield-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XTextFieldsSupplier](http://ooo-site.apache.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextFieldsSupplier.html) has two methods, and it looks like you chose the wrong one. The method to get text fields is `getTextFields()`.

Example code:

```
Reference< XEnumerationAccess > xFieldsEnumAccess = xTextFieldsSupplier->getTextFields();
Reference< XEnumeration > xFieldsEnum = xFieldsEnumAccess->createEnumeration();
Reference< XTextRange > xTextRange;
while ( xFieldsEnum->hasMoreElements() )
{
    Any aNextElement = xFieldsEnum->nextElement();
    Reference< XTextField > xField(aNextElement, UNO_QUERY);
    OUString presentation = xField->getPresentation(true);
    xTextRange = xText->getEnd();
    xTextRange->setString(presentation + OUString::createFromAscii("\n"));
}
```

If you want to deal with text field masters instead, then your code is mostly correct.

```
Any aFieldMaster;
aFieldMaster = xNamedFieldMasters->getByName(*field);
```

**EDIT**:

Here is where `xText` comes from.

```
Reference < XTextDocument > xTextDocument (xComponent,UNO_QUERY);
Reference< XText > xText = xTextDocument->getText();
```

**EDIT 2**:

Here is an example of changing a text field. Start with a new Writer document and go to *Insert -> Field -> More Fields*. Under the *Functions* tab, double-click *Input Field*.  Enter "hello" in the text box area and press OK.

Then, run the following code.

```
Reference< XServiceInfo > xInfo (xField, UNO_QUERY);
OUString sContent;
if (xInfo->supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextField.Input"))
{
    Reference< XPropertySet > xProps (xField, UNO_QUERY);
    Any aContent = xProps->getPropertyValue(OUString::createFromAscii("Content"));
    aContent >>= sContent;
    sContent += OUString::createFromAscii(" there");
    aContent <<= sContent;
    xProps->setPropertyValue(OUString::createFromAscii("Content"), aContent);
    Reference< XRefreshable > xRefreshable (xFieldsEnumAccess, UNO_QUERY);
    xRefreshable->refresh();
}
```

Now, the field contains "hello there".

For more information, please review [Andrew's Macro Document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) section *5.18 User Fields*.

Comment: seems right, thanks. but what does xText variable stands for? where do you get it?

Comment: I still don't get how could I change the text in the xTextField. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @dkezling: See edited answer. If this still doesn't help, then you may need to ask a new question, with a link to this one. Be specific about what is needed.

Comment: I created new topic there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769483/libreoffice-api-uno-need-to-change-users-xtextfield-text with a same question