# Libreoffice API (UNO): need to change user's xTextField text

Tags: c++, libreoffice, uno, libreoffice-writer

Is there any proper way to change text in the user's created xTextField using C++ UNO?
These fields names are com.sun.star.text.fieldmaster.User.[FIELD NAME]

I tried this before, but it didn't help:
[Libreoffice API (UNO) : text and data from xTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509424/libreoffice-api-uno-text-and-data-from-xtextfield)

Also I've tried something like this but still didn't help:

```
// current_field - xTextField I got before 
Reference<XText> xText = Reference<XText>(current_field, UNO_QUERY);
if (!xText.is())
{
    qDebug() << "XText FROM xTextField IS NULL!";
    return;
}

OUStringBuffer bufText;
bufText.append( new_value.utf16() );
std::stringstream textStr;
textStr << bufText.toString();

xText->setString( bufText.toString() );
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read section 5.18 of [Andrew's Macro Document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) as recommended in my other answer? Here is *Listing 5.49* translated into C++. It seems there is a bug in that listing because I had to add `"."` to make it work.

```
OUString sName = OUString::createFromAscii("Author Name");
OUString sServ = OUString::createFromAscii("com.sun.star.text.FieldMaster.User");
OUString sFieldName = sServ + OUString::createFromAscii(".") + sName;
Reference< XMultiServiceFactory > xDocFactory (xTextDocument, UNO_QUERY);
if (xNamedFieldMasters->hasByName(sFieldName))
{
    fieldMaster = xNamedFieldMasters->getByName(sFieldName);
    Reference< XPropertySet> xProps (fieldMaster, UNO_QUERY);
    Any aContent;
    aContent <<= OUString::createFromAscii("Andrew Pitonyak");
    xProps->setPropertyValue(OUString::createFromAscii("Content"), aContent);
}
else
{
    fieldMaster <<= xDocFactory->createInstance(sServ);
    Reference< XPropertySet> xProps (fieldMaster, UNO_QUERY);
    Any aName;
    aName <<= sName;
    xProps->setPropertyValue(OUString::createFromAscii("Name"), aName);
    Any aContent;
    aContent <<= OUString::createFromAscii("Andrew Pitonyak");
    xProps->setPropertyValue(OUString::createFromAscii("Content"), aContent);
}
```

If this code is run on a blank document, the newly created field can be seen by going to *Insert -> Fields -> More Fields, Variables, User Field*.